# access the string in one function with operator[] affects the output of the other function in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

when compile the above function, it will print nothing. While if we comment out "char tmp = num[0]", it will print "===test==="

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void eval(string num)
{
    char tmp = num[0];
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"===test==="<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know it is something wrong in the implementation. I test it in Cygwin, with the following g++ version:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.2.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-5.2.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.2.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-5.2.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

But no such problem in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Could anyone give me an explanation? Really weird. Thanks.

===Updates:

and why I got -2 points for this question?

===Updates2:===

problem solved. We have to install all the related components (gcc-core, g++, libgcc, libsupc, libstdc++ ....) of 5.2.0 version

Comment: What compiler settings?  Ie, what flags?

Comment: g++ test.cpp -o test.out -g 
@Yakk

Comment: Add `-Wall`?  See what it says.

Comment: Wasn't me but it reads like some necessary information was omitted from the question.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk  It says:
test.cpp: In function ‘void eval(std::__cxx11::string)’:
test.cpp:10:7: warning: unused variable ‘tmp’ [-Wunused-variable]
  char tmp = num[0];
       ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:6: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int i;

Comment: Ok, here is a guess: try `WinMain` instead of `main`?  Next, are you sure you sure you are running the code you think you are?

Comment: I think we cannot use WinMain in Cygwin, right? @Yakk

Comment: problem solved. We have to install all the related components (gcc-core, g++, libgcc, libsupc, libstdc++ ....) of 5.2.0 version

Answer (score 1):

The problem is something I've seen before. You will find you have a warning about entry point. The linker defaults to the *first* function as the entry point if it can't determine it. Also, note that moving main() to the first function doesn't fix the problem as the entry point is called with different arguments and a different calling convention.

I'm not sure what you did wrong but it would help if you posted your compilation command.

```
g++ -o test.exe test.cpp
```

is the correct command to compile it; note that we must invoke it as `./test` due to cygwin (current directory is *not* in PATH by default).

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. the compilation command is:

g++ test.cpp -o test.out -g

No warning message during compile. 

and I invoke this executable file with this command:
./test.out